# Why is the 2022 FIFA World Cup beginning in November?

Tags: football, world-cup, international-sports, fifa

The FIFA World Cup is not premiering now in 2022. I tried to watch it but it’s not airing now.

Why is it taking place in November instead of July?

Comment: Please do not delete and repost questions because they are downvoted. To repeat what was written there: "Welcome to Sports Stack Exchange. Can you indicate what reasoning you have so far found unhelpful, or why e.g. [the introduction to the Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_FIFA_World_Cup) is not sufficient?"

Comment: The downvotes, on both this and your original post, are for a lack of research effort. The fact that the 2022 World Cup would be played in November has been known since **2015**, and even if you're only just finding out, the reason why can be found by simply typing your question into Google or (as Philip Kendall noted) looking up the event on Wikipedia. Stack Exchange should be your last resort when asking a question, not the first port of call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The weather in Qatar at this time of year is well above 30°C and up to 45°C *in the shade*, with "RealFeel" temperatures of up to 50°C and even higher.

Right now, as I am writing this answer, it is *midnight* in Qatar and the current temperature in Doha is 32°C with a RealFeel of 39°C (again, that is *in the middle of the night*). The humidity at the moment is 79% which is classified as "Dangerously Humid".

I looked at the forecast and for basically the entirety of August, the weather is in "stay indoors and do not exert yourself or you will die" territory.

The only time you could run a tournament without risking serious bodily harm to the players is in the Winter.